# BotFramework v4 proactive messages only work for some

Tags: python, botframework, python-asyncio, microsoft-teams

my teams bot developed in python with botframework has a strange behaviour. I'll start illustrating the general behaviour:

- every day the bot asks two questions with answers (single or multiple) via an adaptive card.
- the user can answer if interested or not
- the next day the bot sends the answer of the previous day's questions, only to the user who answered them, and then two more questions to all those subscribed to the channel. (This is done via a proactive message).

Here comes the problem: I save a dictionary containing id_user:conversation_reference and retrieve it when I need to contact users. The part of the message about the answers to the previous day's questions reaches all users who have answered correctly, while the part of the message about the day's questions reaches only a few.
Those who receive the day's questions may or may not have answered the previous day's questions. There is the case of a user who answers every day, but who is not notified of the new questions, but there is a command to retrieve them.
I am attaching the code for the previous day's answer.

```
async def _send_proactive_message(id_context, key, result, conv_dict):
    file_name = utils._filename_from_context(id_context[key])
    _, _, question, _, _, _, correct_answer, expl, img1, img2= 
       utils.get_question(key, file_name)
    expl_str = str(expl)
    if(expl_str == 'None'):
        expl_str = 'Nothing'
    correct_answer_str = str(correct_answer)
    for conversation_reference in conv_dict.values():
        if(conversation_reference.user.id in result.keys()):
            if (set(result[conversation_reference.user.id].split(',')) == 
               set(correct_answer_str.split(';'))):
                AppCredentials.trust_service_url(conversation_reference.service_url)
                await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
                    conversation_reference,
                    lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activities([
                    Activity(
                        text="bla bla bla",
                        type=ActivityTypes.message,
                        attachments=[CardFactory.adaptive_card(cards[0])]
                    )
                ]),
                    APP_ID,
                )
```

Now the code for the questions of the day, previously the format was the same, but I still encountered the problems listed above.

```
async def _send_question_of_the_day(conv_dict):
    cards = await utils._create_adaptive_card_attachment()
    now = datetime.now()
    data = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    for conversation_reference in conv_dict.values(): 
        AppCredentials.trust_service_url(conversation_reference.service_url)
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(_send_qptd_sep(cards, data, conversation_reference), 
               timeout=5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass           

async def _send_qptd_sep(cards, data, conversation_reference):
    await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
        conversation_reference,
        lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activities([
        Activity(
            text="bla bla bla",
            type=ActivityTypes.message,
            attachments=[CardFactory.adaptive_card(cards[0])]
        ),
        Activity(
            type=ActivityTypes.message,
            attachments=[CardFactory.adaptive_card(cards[-1])]
        )
    ]),
        APP_ID,
    )
```

I used this timeout method because I was afraid that by sending questions to everyone there would be someone with a corrupted conversation_reference so that the method would fail and the for cycle would not proceed.
But in any case the messages are not sent to everyone. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You need to keep track of two dictionary, one that will store all the user conversation Id(save it when user installed the bot) and the other that will have the conversation reference of user who has provided answer to the question.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Thank you for your reply. I already update the dictionary every time a user posts an answer, so in theory I should already have the most up-to-date conversation reference. Or are you telling me that there are different ones and I have to query one or the other as needed?

Comment: No, as per your scenario what I thought is, you are only having Ids of all those who have given the answer. So most probably you are missing the conversation ref of user who has just installed the bot not answered anytime. To solve that you need to store ids of all user whether they have answer or not when they install the bot.

Comment: @Scaramel - You need to maintain both the conversation reference so that the users who did not replied to any answer but you still be able to send questions based on conversation reference.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - The user's conversation reference is automatically entered into the dictionary the first time the user interacts with the bot.

Comment: Could you please check and share some logs/errors you are getting? It might happen that service get throttled when sending too many request. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit#per-bot-per-thread-limit)